# Physical Memory, CPU usage and I/O processes being max out on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, web-hosting, cpu-usage, shared-hosting

I have made a website in WordPress on GoDaddy Linux Hosting. I am getting an error after each edit in WordPress backend that all the resources are getting utilized and site stops working due to CPU usage, physical memory and I/O processes being filled completely.
Is there any way to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with Godaddy yet? They should be able to help you out with this.

Comment: Yes I have asked from godaddy, but they didn't help

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do is to disable all plugins and check again for high CPU load.

If this solves the problem then you should activate your plugins again one by one and check if your CPU load.

You can also use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to check what cause that high CPU load.

Another thing you should check is the PHP version installed on server. On cPanel you should have something like MultiPHP Manager. Change the PHP version to 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in the last few days
After the used php 7.3, the problem was completely solved
my server load went up to 52, but now it's under 1. Of course, there were other problems that created some areas of databases (not my WordPress script).
also you can see all sql process in phpmyadmin: from top tab-> Status Status -> process 
if you access root server and need to Upgrading PHP with EasyApache for php 7.3 Need to select this

```
    php73-pear
    php73-php-cli
    php73-php-common
    php73-php-devel
    php73-php-fpm
    php73-php-ftp
    php73-php-litespeed
    php73-php-mysqlnd
    php73-php-pdo
    php73-php-posix
    php73-php-xml
    php73-runtime
    php73-scldevel
```

Answer (score 0):

High CPU in WP can be helped by improving the indexes on `wp_postmeta` as discussed here:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score -1):

It happens because the resources you are using are not optimized.

You can go to `cpanel>optimize site>` and put the mime types you want to optimize eg. `img/png img/jpg`.

This might help you out.

Answer (score -1):

You need to contact to your hosting provider and upgrade your plan for high resources. Or you can contact your developer to optimize the site code to reduce the CPU usage.

Regards,